# how to avoid duplication while joining five tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have five tables they are jobs,keyword,keyword_master,location_master,company_master these are my tables now what is the question is i want to join five tables based on jobs.id i wrote the query for joining all the five tables but here i facing problem what is the problem is for single job.id their are more than one skills in keywor and keyword_master, while joining my job.id becoming duplicate based on how many skills stored in keyword and keyword_master same for remaining table also how to solve this.

### jobs

id location_id company_id...etc

### keyword

id job_id keyword_id

### keyword_master

id name

### comapany_master

id name

### location_master

id city

I want output as

### jobs.id keyword.job_id keyword.keyword_id keyword_master.name location_master.city company_master.name

|1    1   1   php   xyz  xxx
|     1   2   js
|     1   3   java
|     1   4   js
 instead of 
1     1   1   php   xyz  xxx
1     1   2   js    xyz  xxx
1     1   3   java  xyz  xxx
1     1   4   js    xyz  xxx

here is my query

```
    $this->db->select('jobs.*,jobs.id as newjobid,keyword.*,keyword_master.name as new_name,keyword_master.id as new_id,company_master.*,company_master.id as cm_id,location_master.*');
    $this->db->from('jobs');
    $this->db->join('keyword','keyword.job_id=jobs.id','left');
    $this->db->join('keyword_master','keyword_master.id=keyword.keyword_id','left');
    $this->db->join('location_master','location_master.id=jobs.location','left');
    $this->db->join('comppany_master','company_master.id=jobs.company_id','left');
```

Comment: Its better if you implement your duplicate records logic in application level code using if else till same job and display its related data

Comment: why are you joining to the `keyword` and `keyword_master` tables if you aren't interested in all of the matching data?

Comment: I want data from all the table that is why i kept foreign key in all the table @ pala

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT works in this case ?

Comment: I tried DISTINCT but not worked

Comment: you haven't explained what you want. you're talking about duplicates - there are no duplicates. the rows differ. so what do you want? only the first skill?

Comment: @niyou consider in jobs table job.id is 1 in keyword table job_id ll store  1 1 1 1 and keyword_id is 1 2 3 4 in keyword_master table id is 1 2 3 4 name  php js codeigniter c i want output as job.id 1 and skill should be php js codeigniter c instead of 1 php,1js,1 codeigniter, 1 c

Comment: So you want the keywords as one column? This is considered bad normalization. As suggested above, you should handle combining the keywords in application rather than in the query

Comment: The way to do what you have in mind is with `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Please update your question with table structure and expected answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your query you have typos within your query

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('j.*,l.city as loc_city,l.id as loc_id,km.name as key_name,km.id as key_id,c.id as comp_id,c.name as comp_name',false);
$this->db->from('jobs j');
$this->db->join('keyword k','k.job_id=j.id','left');
$this->db->join('keyword_master km','km.id = k.keyword_id','left');
$this->db->join('location_master l','l.id = j.location_id','left');
$this->db->join('comppany_master c','c.id = j.company_id','left');
```

Comment: thank u code working but job id is repeating for number of skills stored in keyword_master

Comment: thank you for your reply i upload a image take a look your code gives same result

Comment: So what you really wanted to have list of comma separated values

Comment: no friend see the company_name in image its repeating i dont want these repeating that is my question

Comment: these repeating occurs because of keyword table have more record for single job.id

Comment: Distinct will not always work. You should add ->group_by("name_of_the_column_which_needs_to_be unique");